# App crashes : while fetching alt-tag for celebrity names

Tags: android

I am working on Guess Celebrity app and for celebrity names and pictures I was using posh24.

I tried fetching source code first and printing it to logs it worked. Then I decided to fetch names as they were alt tags for images. However, when I did that app crashed and didn't even register names to the logs.

[Here are my MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml files.](https://gist.github.com/mukundmadhav/a60061bae0c7343c182fd95afeba601e)

UPDATE: [Here is the logcat.](https://www.docdroid.net/file/download/Bd6dt13/logcat.pdf)

Comment: Post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

IMO the problem is in the AsyncTask, I'm not sure but you have to override onPostExcecute, this method runs on the UI thread which can touch views :)

Comment: add to your Background class onPostExcecute method (Ctrl + O in AS), you will have sure that after excecute this method you will have results (but may be null there so you have to check if result != null). Then you can simply assign values from array to your views.

Comment: @Peter Stewart Logcat shows ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, It means problem with array.

Comment: Anil, yes you have a right, there is an ArrayIndex... exception, I found at the last pages of the logcat nullpointer exception